# Picking out individual items from an Observable array

Tags: angular, observable

If I have a method in a service in Angular that returns an `Observable<MyModel[]>`, how can I do something like this:

`myService.myMethod().map(items => item)`

In other words, how can I pick out each `item` in the `items` array and then do something with it?

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns an observable, which emits an array of items. So you want to transform that into a different stream. You're correctly suing your `map` here. Now, *how* do you want to transform each element from an array? Use `map` again, only this time it will come from `Array` prototype instead from `Rx.Observable`:

```
myService.myMethod().map(items => items.map(item => /* transform */))
```